# jdbc connectivity (ping failure)?

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, oracle10g

I want to connect(jdbc connectivity) oracle 10g with eclipse software, but unfortunately i am getting ping failure message.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like the server name is wrong, or the port number is wrong, or there's a firewall preventing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Connection URL is incorrect. Are you sure **server** is the correct name for your host? If you installed it locally try using **127.0.0.1** or **localhost** instead.